# I want to use a Button to add the text in a TextBox to a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: View of the listview and textbox]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new AddItem();

        taskList.ItemsSource = new List<AddItem>
        {
            new AddItem()
            {
                Title = "Task1",
            },
            new AddItem()
            {
                Title = "Task2",
            },
        };
    }
   
    private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        taskList.SelectedItem = new AddItem();
    }
```

I want to add the `Text` in the `TextBox` as an `AddItem` to the `ListView` using a `Button`, but I don't know how to add the value to the `ListView`. The name of the `TextBox` is `inputTitle`.

Comment: What is the name of your textbox ? If it doesn't have a Name: tag, you should add one, this will allow you to get its Text property.

Comment: When clicking on `Add`, you want to create another item in the task list that will contain a checkbox, a label, and a button to remove it, is this what need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to modify the collection you have to use an [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) that supports notifying collection changes through the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1) interface that tiggers updating your `ListView`. `List<T>` does not support that, so your user interface will not be updated when adding, removing or replacing items in the collection.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   private ObservableCollection<AddItem> _myItems;

   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      DataContext = new AddItem();

      _myItems = new ObservableCollection<AddItem>
      {
         new AddItem()
         {
            Title = "Task1",
         },
         new AddItem()
         {
            Title = "Task2",
         },
      };

      taskList.ItemsSource = _myItems;
   }

   private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      var newItem = new AddItem()
      {
         Title = inputTitle.Text,
      };

      _myItems.Add(newItem);
      taskList.SelectedItem = newItem;
   }
}
```

You should consider checking if the `Text` is empty, so you avoid adding useless items or deactivate the button if the `TextBox` is empty.